# How to implement a robust description list with a counter for the item labels that works properly with hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, lists, counters, description

Hope the title is not too confusing and describes what I meant. Here is the thing: I need to have a list where the items have an incremental counter but also have some customized words attached. I.e., I want to have a list like:

```
Case 1 (a<b): XXX

Case 2 (b<c): YYY

Case 3 (c<d): ZZZ
```

where the '1', '2', and '3' are counters and I would like to reference them with proper hyperref. E.g, in other places, I may have something like:

```
In Case 1, we only need to do XXX.
```

where the '1' is not hardcoded and is derived from '\ref{SomeLabel}'. Furthermore, I would like the hyperref to work with the labels/refs.

Currently, I figured out a solution which displays correctly but the hyperref is not working properly. My solution is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{desccounter}
\newcommand{\descitem}[1]{\refstepcounter{desccounter}\item[Case \thedesccounter{} #1]}

\begin{document}

The first list:

\setcounter{desccounter}{0}
\begin{description}

\descitem{$(a<b)$}:\label{Label1} XXX

\descitem{$(b<c)$}:\label{Label2} YYY

\descitem{$(c<d)$}:\label{Label3} ZZZ

\end{description}

Refs to the first list: Case \ref{Label1}, Case \ref{Label2}, Case \ref{Label3}.

\bigskip

The second list:

\setcounter{desccounter}{0}
\begin{description}

\descitem{$(x=y)$}:\label{Label4} AAA

\descitem{$(y=z)$}:\label{Label5} BBB

\descitem{$(z=w)$}:\label{Label6} CCC

\end{description}

Refs to the second list: Case \ref{Label4}, Case \ref{Label5}, Case \ref{Label6}.

\end{document}
```

And the rendered result is:

[image]

You can see that display is correct, but hyperref is not: If you click the hyper links for the second list, you will be directed to the first list.

Since I am not an expert in the counter/label/ref thing in Latex, any experts can help on this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `\theHdesccounter` and unique value across the document. E.g. (`Item` is used by hyperref in various places, you can increase it but you shouldn't reset it to zero):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{desccounter}
\renewcommand\theHdesccounter{\theItem.\arabic{desccounter}}
\newcommand{\descitem}[1]{\stepcounter{Item}\refstepcounter{desccounter}\item[Case \thedesccounter{} #1]}

\begin{document}

The first list:

\setcounter{desccounter}{0}
\begin{description}

\descitem{$(a<b)$}:\label{Label1} XXX

\descitem{$(b<c)$}:\label{Label2} YYY

\descitem{$(c<d)$}:\label{Label3} ZZZ

\end{description}

Refs to the first list: Case \ref{Label1}, Case \ref{Label2}, Case \ref{Label3}.

\bigskip

The second list:

\setcounter{desccounter}{0}
\begin{description}

\descitem{$(x=y)$}:\label{Label4} AAA

\descitem{$(y=z)$}:\label{Label5} BBB

\descitem{$(z=w)$}:\label{Label6} CCC

\end{description}

Refs to the second list: Case \ref{Label4}, Case \ref{Label5}, Case \ref{Label6}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution works. But can you please explain it? Is 'Item' a counter defined by hyperref? Also, what is `theHdesccounter'? Why redefining the macro makes it work? Thanks!

Comment: hyperref uses internally \theHdesccounter to create the anchor name, by default this is defined as \arabic{desccounter} but this doesn't give unique names in your document. Item is a counter from hyperref that is uses also in other lists.